# TSQL query to delete all files in a directory using xp

Tags: sql, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to delete all the files in specific directory and below is the query I am trying to exec. But its throwing the **error as 'invalid parameter'**

```
EXEC master.sys.xp_delete_files '\\nmm\Test\*';
```

Also I am trying to delete specific specific files with specific file extension too, .csv files like below.

```
 EXEC master.sys.xp_delete_files '\\nmm\Test\*csv';
```

Tried

Answer (score 0):

Try to define full path to your file, like this:

```sql
EXEC master.sys.xp_delete_files 'T:\nmm\Test\*.csv';
```

Comment: Command executed correctly but file still there